# problems after updating ubuntu14. 04 to 16.01

Tags: 14.04, updates

I was updating my Ubuntu 14.04 and everything was fine. But suddenly, my laptop had shut down. Now, Ubuntu is loading... but only shows a DOS-like environment.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

dos like environment is tty session.
Try these commands

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell gnome
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```